# fraction shortening C++

Tags: c++, function, short

I need to short fraction :
4/5 * 3/4 = 12/20 , but i need to short it so answer must be: 3/5.
I know that I must to use this function:

```
int NWD(int m1,int m2){
   int d;
   while((m1!=0)&&(m2!=0)){
    if(m1>=m2) m1=m1%m2;
    else m2=m2%m1;
    return d=m1+m2;}
    }
```

So can you help me?

Comment: Why must you use that function? It doesn't appear to do anything useful, or even be coherently written.

Comment: Have you tried googling GCD?

Comment: Yes i have tryied googling, but i don't understand how to use this.

Comment: Euclid figured it out in 300BC - http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~schmidt/301s12/Exercises/euclid_alg.html

Answer (score 2):

you need to divide both the numerator and denominator by the GCD of the two numbers.

Calculate GCD int

```
gcdr ( int a, int b )
{
  if ( a==0 ) return b;
  return gcdr ( b%a, a );
}
```

courtesy: [for GCD code snippet](http://www.math.wustl.edu/~victor/mfmm/compaa/gcd.c)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify such fractions by dividing both the numerator and the denominator by the greatest common divisor of the two. A common method for calculating a GCD is the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the correct version of your function.

```
int NWD(int m1,int m2){
   while((m1!=0)&&(m2!=0)){
    if(m1>=m2) m1=m1%m2;
    else m2=m2%m1;
   }
   return m1+m2;
}

int num = 12;
int den = 20;
int d = NWD(num,den);
cout << num/d << '/' << den/d;
```

Untested code.